# Let $\alpha>0, \beta \ge0$ and $f: R \to R$ be continuous at $0$ with $f(0)=\beta$...

Tags: calculus, functions

Let $\alpha>0, \beta\ge0$ and $f: R \to R$ be continuous at 0 with $f(0)=\beta$.

If $g(x)=|x|^{\alpha}f(x)$ is differentiable at $0$, then which of the following are true?

(A) $\alpha=1$ and $\beta=1$

(B) $0<\alpha<1$ and $\beta=0$

(C) $\alpha \ge1$ and $\beta=0$

(D)$\alpha>0$ and $\beta>1$

If we substitute 0 in $g(x)$ we get $g(0)=|0|^{\alpha}\beta$ which is 0 then how we can choose what value $\alpha$ and $\beta$ holds?

Comment: Wow. I am still too inexperienced and I have never seen such multiple choice!

Comment: hmm, should we change the question to $\beta \geq 0$?

Comment: Would it be the case that all answers are wrong? Take $alpha =2$ then $f$ can be any differentiable function (E.g. f ≡ $\beta$).

Comment: I think the answer would be $\alpha > 1$ or $\beta = 0$.

Comment: There are problems in the way your question is framed. One can easily spot that $g(0)$ is undefined. If $\alpha$ is a real number then the expression $k^{\alpha} $ is defined only when $k>0$. Thus $g(0)=0^{\alpha}f(0)$ does not make any sense. The question should add that $g(0)=0$ in which case it is differentiable at $0$ if $\alpha>1$.

Comment: If $g(0)=0$ then we can also easily show that $g'(0)=0$ if $\alpha=1,\beta=0$.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, $g(x)$ should be continuous at $0$.
Thus LHL=RHL

$$\lim_{x\to0^-}|x|^{\alpha}.f(x)=\lim_{x\to0^+}|x|^{\alpha}.f(x)$$
$$\lim_{x\to0^-}|x|^{\alpha}.f(x)=\lim_{x\to0^+}|x|^{\alpha}.f(x)$$
$$|-0.00001|^{\alpha}.\beta=|0.00001|^{\alpha}.\beta$$
This shows that $\alpha$ must be $1$ or $0<\alpha<1$ so that the value $|x|$ doesn't diverges much.

Now, For diffrenciation:

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}$$
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{|x+h|^\alpha f(x+h)-|x|^\alpha.f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{|x-h|^\alpha f(x-h)-|x|^\alpha.f(x)}{-h}$$

From this, you may conclude that $\beta=0$.

Comment: Your approach certainly give me much inspiration. But I have a concern. The function $h(x)=|x|^\alpha$ is continuous at 0. Therefore if we take $f(x)=x$, then $g(x)=xh(x)$ is differentiable at 0. Does is matter that $\alpha$ must be between 0 and 1 then?

Comment: I think there is no need to check for continuity of $g$ provided we are given additional information that $g(0)=0$. The problem is insoluble if this is not given. Also I don't see why you write numbers like $0.00001$ in your answer. Also how can we conclude $\beta=0$? And we have to check differentiability of $g$ at $0$ and not at some general point $x$.

Comment: Your answer certainly is not right, the correct answer given is $\alpha \ge 0$ abd $\beta=0$

Comment: @ParamanandSingh it's not given that $g(0)=0$ and this is why I am having problem with the question to solve.

Comment: @ItiShree: in that case your problem is not solvable. Since $g(0)$ is not defined we can't talk about its derivative at $0$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh are you sure? Cause it's from statitical institute  exam and they never release proper method of answer. Anyways thanks for telling.

Comment: @ItiShree: Argument by authority has no place in any scientific activity. When IIT JEE exam papers have errors (not typos but logical faults) then other Institutes exam papers may also have issues. In your current question it is best to mention that there is an issue and work according to the assumption $g(0)=0$.